# Apache Camel - Rest Endpoint - How to stop camel copying all request header in response

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

Is there any global setting or something available to stop camel copying all request header in the response.
The endpoint looks like something similar to <camel:route id="doSomething">
<camel:from uri="rest:post:///doSomething" />....

Comment: Inserting a `<removeHeaders pattern="*"/>` in your route can do the job, but I guess you mean a GLOBAL setting for the whole Camel Context ?

Comment: yes Globally, and it should remove only from the final response of rest api, not any intermediate forwarding endpoints.

Answer (score 0):

You may consider using [onCompletion](https://camel.apache.org/manual/oncompletion.html)
It can be set on route as well global level.
Also verify the **mode** you need.

```
<onCompletion mode="BeforeConsumer">
   <removeHeaders pattern="*"/>
</onCompletion>
```